# How to show that $\frac{1}{u} q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} =q^2 q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} \frac{1}{u} $?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, representation-theory

Let $q$ be a complex number. Let $u$ be a variable. How to show that $\frac{1}{u} q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} =q^2 q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} \frac{1}{u} $?

I think that it suffices to show that $q^2 u q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} = q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} u$. We also have $u\frac{d}{du} + 1= \frac{d}{du}u$. But how to prove that $q^2 u q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} = q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} u$? Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be easier to use the variable $v = \frac{1}{2}\log u$ so that $2u\frac{d}{du} = \frac{d}{dv}$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v = \frac{1}{2} \log u$. Then $u=e^{2v}$ and $\frac{d}{dv} = \frac{d}{d(\frac{1}{2} \log u)} = \frac{d}{ \frac{1}{2u} du} = 2u\frac{d}{du}$.

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Then we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{du} e^{au} = e^{au} (\frac{d}{du} + a).
\end{align}
By induction, we have 
\begin{align}
(\frac{d}{du})^k e^{au} = e^{au} (\frac{d}{du} + a)^k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.
\end{align}
Let $b \in \mathbb{C}$. We have 
\begin{align}
(b\frac{d}{du})^k e^{au} = b^k( e^{au} (\frac{d}{du} + a)^k ) =  e^{au} (b\frac{d}{du} + ab)^k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}.
\end{align}
Therefore for $c \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
\begin{align}
e^{c \frac{d}{du}} e^{au} = e^{au} e^{c \frac{d}{du} + a c} = e^{au} e^{c \frac{d}{du}} e^{ac}.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} u & = q^{\frac{d}{dv}} e^{2v} \\
& = e^{(\log q)\frac{d}{dv}} e^{2v} \\
& = e^{2v} e^{(\log q)\frac{d}{dv}} e^{2 \log q} \\
& = e^{2v} q^{ \frac{d}{dv}} q^2 \\
& = u q^{2u\frac{d}{du}} q^2.
\end{align}